# How do I properly publish tombstone messages to compacted kafka topic from within a quarkus application?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

From within a [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) application I need to publish tombstone messages to a compacted Apache Kafka topic. As my use-case is imperative I use an `Emitter` for sending messages to the topic ([as suggested in the quarkus blog](https://quarkus.io/blog/reactive-messaging-emitter/)). The code for *non-tombstone* messages (with payload) is:

```
@Dependent
public class Publisher {

  @Inject
  @Channel("theChannelName")
  Emitter<MyDataStructure> emitter;

  public CompletionStage<Void> publish(final MyDataStructure myData) {
    OutgoingKafkaRecordMetadata<String> metadata =
        OutgoingKafkaRecordMetadata.<String>builder()
            .withKey(myData.getTopicKey())
            .build();
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(
        () -> emitter.send(Message.of(myData).addMetadata(metadata)));
  }
}
```

The `Emitter` also implements `<M extends Message<? extends T>> void send(M msg)` which I hoped would allow me to craft a `Message` with payload of `null` as tombstone message. Unfortunately all implementations of the `Message.of(..)` factory method, that allow to provide metadata (which is needed to provide the message-key), specify that *payload, must not be {@code null}*.

What is the proper way (following Quarkus / SmallRye Reactive Messaging concepts) to publish tombstone messages to a Kafka topic using an `Emitter`?

Comment: I'd suggest to use `KafkaRecord.of()`. `KafkaRecord` is a `Message`, and while its `of` methods also document that `value` must not be `null`, that isn't actually enforced. If that works for you, let's just get that documentation updated :-)

Comment: @Ladicek While your suggestion might solve the issue right now, using an API in a way it's seemingly not intended to be used is also bad advice. From what you say it seems like a bug which, when fixed, will cause the application to break.

Comment: Another option may be (I'm not entirely sure, but it _should_ work) to use the `Record` class as a message payload. That enables setting both key and value, and both are documented to allow `null` (https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/3.3/kafka/kafka.html#_sending_keyvalue_pairs). So something like `emitter.send(Record.of(myData.getTopicKey(), null))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using the `Record` class (see [documentation](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/3.3/kafka/kafka.html#_sending_keyvalue_pairs)).
A `Record` is a key/value pair, which represents the key and value of the Kafka record to write. Both can be `null`, but in your case, only the value part should be `null`: `Record.of(key, null);`.

So, you need to change the type of the Emitter to be `Record<Key, Value>`, such as:

```
@Dependent
public class Publisher {

  @Inject
  @Channel("theChannelName")
  Emitter<Record<Key, MyDataStructure>> emitter;

  public CompletionStage<Void> publish(final MyDataStructure myData) {
      return emitter.send(Record.of(myData.getTopicKey(), null);
  }
}
```

While `runAsync` is convenient, emitters are already async. So, no need to use that. In addition, the behavior can be dramatic in containers (if your level of parallelism is less than 2).

My code returned the result of the `send` method which is a `CompletionStage`. That stage will be completed when the record is written in Kafka (and acked by the broker).